# how to change textbox.text when i create instance from form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I call one method from myclass that method located in my form and in method I set `textbox.text="xyz"` but my textbox's text does not change.
in addition , form2 is showing that i call aa().
where is my mistake?

```
class a
{
   private void aa()
   {
       Form2 f2 = new Form2();
       f2.b();
   }
}

public partial class Form2 : form
{
    public void b()
    {
       textbox1.text= "xyz";
    }
}
```

Comment: try this:  Form2 f2 = new Form2();    f2.show();
       f2.b();

Comment: Inside `aa()` method you're creating a new `Form2` but where are you calling `Show()` or `ShowDialog()` on it?

Comment: you aren't showing your new form. It's hard to see why you think the textbox isn't changing, because it shouldn't even be visible.

Comment: @LosPollosHermanos are you still in business? Who's running the show now? ;)

Comment: @Sach its secret!

Comment: Missing calling Show() method of the object of form you created.

Comment: @LosPollosHermanos form2  is showing that i call aa()

Comment: At a guess maybe you already have a different copy of Form2 which is already visible? But you have created a new copy and your code updates that, not any previous version.

Answer (score 0):

First, before call `f2.b();` to update some controls make sure that the window handle is created:

```
 f2.Show();
```

If you call function `aa()` from another `Form`(let's say from `Form1`) make the `Thread-Safe Call` which involves invoking the thread if required.

```
class a
{
    private void aa()
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.Show();
        f2.b();
    }
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public void b()
    {
        Action a = delegate
        {
            UpdateControls();
        };

        MethodInvoker Invoker = new MethodInvoker(a);

        if (InvokeRequired)
            this.Invoke(Invoker);
        else
            a();
    }

    public void UpdateControls()
    {
        textbox1.Text = "xyz";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class a
{
    Form f1;
    a(Form f){
        f1 = f;
    }
   private void aa()
   {
       f1.b();
   }
}
public partial class Form2 : form
{
    public void b()
    {
       textbox1.text= "xyz";
    }
    private void button1.Clicked(args, events){
        a obj = new a(this.Form);
        obj.aa();
    }
}
```

Comment: "try this"...because? You should explain the difference between your code and the original so people know why it helps.